# xyplot add data frame line # above points

Tags: r, point, label, lattice

I have searched high and low for help on this and am generally confused, and have come up with the following which works if the plot has already been executed in r studio.

```
p<-xyplot(A~B
           ,data=X
           ,group=diffStr
           ,par.settings=myPars
           ,auto.key=list(title="xxxx", space="top", cex=myCex))


    trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
    panel.text(x=p$panel.args[[1]]$x,y=p$panel.args[[1]]$y,labels = seq.int(nrow(X)), pos=3, cex=0.7, col="red")
    trellis.unfocus()
```

this works in r studio but only if i have already run xyplot before hand without saving into p, but when i run in knitr it breaks. I just want my 100 points to have the numeric position in the data frame above it.

thanks